# How to get PDF page dimensions

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have an existing pdf and extracting text from the pdf. Here is the code I have already

```
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf.parser;
using System.IO;

public string ReadPdfFile(string fileName)
{
    StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

    if (File.Exists(fileName))
    {
        PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

        for (int page = 1; page <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; page++)
        {
            ITextExtractionStrategy strategy = new SimpleTextExtractionStrategy();
            string currentText = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(pdfReader, page, strategy);

            currentText = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(ASCIIEncoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, Encoding.UTF8, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(currentText)));
            text.Append(currentText);
        }
        pdfReader.Close();
    }
    return text.ToString();
}
```

I would like to get the dimensions of the pdf page. I need the dimensions so I can create a wrapper class that contains this information. Then the class can determine if rectangles are out of bounds.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> I would like to get the dimensions of the pdf page.

The `PdfReader` class supplies methods to retrieve them:

```
PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(fileName);

Rectangle mediabox = pdfReader.GetPageSize(pageNr);
Rectangle cropbox = pdfReader.GetCropBox(pageNr);
```

Depending on which dimensions you actually need, use either of those.

Comment: And what is the crop box compared to the page size?

Comment: @ˈvɔlə *"And what is the crop box compared to the page size?"* - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13240546/1729265) for a characterization of the boxes (media, crop, bleed, trim, art).

Answer (score 1):

how about using this:-

```
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(m);
PdfImportedPage page = writer.GetImportedPage(pdfReader, i);
// size information
page.PageSize.Width;
page.PageSize.Height;
```

Comment: Importing a page is totally unnecessary, `PdfReader` already offers methods to return the page dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
using iText.Kernel.Pdf;

PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(yourfile);
PdfDocument pdf = new PdfDocument(pdfReader);

var height = pdf.GetPage(1).GetPageSize().GetHeight();
var width = pdf.GetPage(1).GetPageSize().GetWidth();
```

Where 1 is the number of the page that you want to extract the dimension. If you want to convert the result to mm, just do that:

```
var widthMM = width*25,4/72
```