# Bootstrap DateTime Picker not Showing properly its hiding by screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

How to display full datetime picker in the screen. I tried `position:relative` but not working. Please help me..
HTML code :

```
<div style="position:relative">
<div class="input-group date form_startdatetime" data-date-format="dd M yyyy - HH:ii P" data-link-field="dtp_startdate">
     <input class="form-control" size="16" type="text" name="sDateTime" tabindex="7">
</div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./datetimepicker3/jquery/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./datetimepicker3/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./datetimepicker3/datetimepicker/js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('.form_startdatetime').datetimepicker({
    //language:  'fr',
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn:  1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    showMeridian: 1

});
</script>
```

See picture of output..
[image]

Comment: but... what is your expected position? Should it follow when you scroll?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you mean. Is the problem that the calendar it is being cut if the screen height is not high enough? Could you try explaining more what would you like to achieve?

Comment: What version of bootstrap js library are you using? Also, could you perhaps try reproducing this in Codepen perhaps? In that way, someone would be able to help you much better. I see that the datepicker here works like you would want to out of the box: https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Comment: The datatime picker should show on the top, when screen is not enough

Comment: Also, what is the version of the datepicker plugin version?

Comment: Check if the datepicker you are using is of the same version as the datepicker in this link and then check if the container property like Ankit is suggesting is indeed needed. Could be even though there is no container property needed in the link above (https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/).

Comment: the version is Bootstrap 3 date time picker and my datetime picker link [www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker](http://www.malot.fr/bootstrap-datetimepicker).

Answer (score 2):

From Your comment, I see this in the documentation.

#### pickerPosition

String. **Default**: `'bottom-right'` (other value supported : 'bottom-left')

This option is currently only available in the component implementation. With it, you can place the picker just under the input field.

I am adding a sample example for better understanding of **Positioning**.

```
<div class="input-append date form_datetime">
    <input size="16" type="text" value="" readonly>
    <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-th"></i></span>
</div>
 
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".form_datetime").datetimepicker({
        format: "dd MM yyyy - hh:ii",
        autoclose: true,
        todayBtn: true,
        pickerPosition: "bottom-left"
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry isn't not working.. I am using boostrap-datetimepicker.

Comment: See https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/. This plugin does not need a container property to achieve what he wants. It should work out of the box.

Comment: I have updated with the reference link and example. @AlexRebula

Comment: @RamAndroid Try `orientation` attribute.

Comment: As I wrote previously, I don't believe he needs a property at all as the plugin should position itself properly on click event out of the box as shown in the link I pasted.

Comment: I have updated my answer with the example of your used plugin. Hope it will help. @RamAndroid