# Apache PDFBox - Unable to reduce the size of the content in PDF

Tags: java, apache, pdf, pdfbox

I am trying to use PDFBox to resize PDFs so that I can make some space for header and footer later. I am able to do it for most cases except when the page size is way much large.

Page Width & Height = 3168.0 :: 22023.0 (pts)

I am using the following code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
    //String pdfFilename = "/MuhimbiPOC/Templates/Source_doc_withheaderfooter.pdf";
    //String pdfFilename = "/MuhimbiPOC/Templates/3.pdf";
    String pdfFilename = "/MuhimbiPOC/Templates/PDFsam_3.pdf";
    PDDocument document = PDDocument.load(new File(pdfFilename));
    PDDocument documentPDF = new PDDocument();
    PDFRenderer pdfRenderer = new PDFRenderer(document);
    PDPage pge = new PDPage();
    int pageCounter = 0;
    for (PDPage page : document.getPages())
    {

        final PDRectangle mediaBox = page.getMediaBox();
        mediaBox.setUpperRightX((float) (page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightX()));
        mediaBox.setUpperRightY(page.getMediaBox().getUpperRightY() + page.getMediaBox().getHeight() * 0.1f);
        mediaBox.setLowerLeftY(page.getMediaBox().getLowerLeftY() - page.getMediaBox().getHeight() * 0.1f); 
        System.out.println("====================================");
        System.out.println((float) (page.getMediaBox().getWidth()) + " :: " + page.getMediaBox().getHeight());
        System.out.println(mediaBox.getWidth() + " :: " + mediaBox.getHeight());
        System.out.println("====================================");
        // note that the page number parameter is zero based
        page.setMediaBox(mediaBox);
    }
    System.out.println("No. of Pages :: " + document.getNumberOfPages());
    document.save(pdfFilename + "_test.pdf");
    System.out.println("Task Completed ... @ " + new Date());
    document.close();


}
 catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

This works perfectly for every cases except with the one i mentioned.

Comment: You only change the MediaBox. More important is the CropBox (which defaults to the MediaBox if it is not explicitly given). Thus, update the CropBox, too.

Comment: @mkl Thanks for the tip. That worked quite well :)

Comment: In that case I'll make that comment an actual answer you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

The OP's code only reads and updates the **MediaBox** of the page. But the **CropBox** is more important for the visible size of a page. You can find an enumeration and description of the different boxes one can define on a page in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13240546/1729265).

The reason why the code works most of the time in spite of this, is that the **CropBox** defaults to the **MediaBox** if it is not explicitly given.

Thus, the code should be updated to update both the **MediaBox** and the **CropBox** if the latter also is explicitly given for a page.