# Not getting a right resolution of the page of PDF in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, cgpdfdocument

I want to know the resolution of the page of PDF. I have tried one solution but getting the wrong resolution (**612 x 792**). But a correct resolution is **816x1056**.

```
guard let provider = CGDataProvider(data: fileData as CFData) else { return }
guard let coreDocument = CGPDFDocument(provider) else { return }
guard let page = coreDocument.page(at: 0) else { return }

let size = page.getBoxRect(.mediaBox).size
```

Comment: try `let size = page.getBoxRect(.cropBox).size`

Comment: @LeoDabus getting the wrong size.

Comment: A pdf does not have a resolution. Merely if there is a single page filling bitmap image (without rotation or skewing), you might derive some resolution value. A crop box of 612 x 792 by the way usually means a letter size page.

Comment: @mkl thanks, But when i view in adobe reader get resolution 816x1056. but by above code i get resolution 612 x 792.

Comment: *"when i view in adobe reader get resolution 816x1056"* - where exactly in Adobe Reader do you get that resolution? That "resolution" most likely gives you the page dimensions in px while the code above gives you the page dimensions in pt, and the former numbers equal 4/3 times the latter ones.

Comment: @mkl ok thanks got a solution. Can you write in the answer? so i accept that as correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "resolution" you are looking for is given in px (= <sup>1</sup>/<sub>96</sub> in) while the dimensions in PDFs are given in pt (= <sup>1</sup>/<sub>72</sub> in).

Thus, you can calculate your desired output by multiplying the dimensions from the PDF by <sup>4</sup>/<sub>3</sub>.

---

Some asides...

Strictly speaking PDF pages don't have *"resolutions"* as such because PDF is a vector format. Of course, though, their pages have *dimensions* which is what you are determining.

Furthermore, you indeed should first look for the **CropBox** and only in its absence use the **MediatBox**. You can read about all the defined boxes [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13240546/1729265).