# How to get height and width of a pdf while using PDF BOX

Tags: java, pdfbox

Here is a question: When I use PDF Box, I have no idea how to get height and width of a PDF file. I cannot see any method for *get*.

```
PDDocument pdDocument = getPDDocument(fis);
PDPage doc = pdDocument.getPage(0);
```

Comment: What is the "height" of a PDF file? Maybe you mean the height of a page in the PDF document?

Comment: Retrieve the `Crobox` and the `Rotation` of the page.

Comment: Unrelated - assuming that "fis" is a FileInputStream, you can get better performance by using a File directly.

Comment: thanks above,my English is not very good,I will improve my expression next time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside of each `PDPage` you have a method called `getMediaBox()` that returns a `PDRectangle`. You can obtain the height and the width.

Be careful with the UOM that represent the width and height.

https://pdfbox.apache.org/docs/2.0.0/javadocs/org/apache/pdfbox/pdmodel/PDPage.html#getMediaBox()

Comment: If you want the *visible* page size, you should use the **CropBox** instead. Read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13240546/1729265) for an overview of the boxes defined for a page. And check the page **Rotate** value, if it's 90 or 270, you have to switch width and height.